# GDB and G++ Changing Random Parameters to 0

Tags: c++, gdb, g++, arduino, cortex-m

I am writing a library allow a brand new WiFi system-on-a-chip (processor is a cortex-m4) to function with the Arduino WiFi api, however I'm running into a **very** weird bug while debugging with GDB.

Often, parameters passed to functions will change to 0 for no reason. For example, while testing my library, I call `delay(1000)`, however my sketch was running much faster than I expected. Breaking the execution at the call of delay revealed that in actuality, `delay(0)` was being called...
[image: line 63 highlighted - should delay for 1000 ms]
[image: paused execution in delay - parameter has changed from 1000 to 0?!]
This isn't that big of a deal, but this has far worse implications for strings. For example, passing in a string to `strlen()` often causes huge problems. The pointer will get changed to `(char*) 0x0`, 
and then `strlen(0x0)` returns several thousand bytes because a null character isn't encountered for a while.

Even worse, the implicit *`this`* pointer often gets changed to `0x0` as well, changing the value of all the instance's variables
[image]

I've tried everything I can think of. I've switched to a different development board, I've recompiled all my code and the IDE, I've turned off all optimization (using `-O0`). I'm lost.

**Why are parameters getting changed to 0 for apparently no reason?**

edit *So, it sounds like this is definitely a stack overflow issue (how appropriate), so I guess the easiest fix would be to make my local stack larger. I'm compiling with arm-none-eabi-g++, so what is the command line argument that I can use to make my stack larger? For that matter, what is the default stack size?*

Comment: So where in your while-loop do you increment `i` while reading the udp packet?

Comment: Thanks for catching that! But that doesn't change the fact that random parameters are getting changed to 0. If you look at the debug console, you'll see `WiFiUDP::remotePort(this=0x0)`. I know, for certain, that the udp instance is not located at `0x0`.

Comment: "This isn't that big of a deal " - I can assure you it isn't random, and is a *very* big deal. Somewhere, local stack is being overstepped and writing on your parameters. And I don't believe there is enough here to even fathom a guess where. I suggest running this through Valgrind. It is likely it will show you where the overstep is. That, of course, assuming your gdb isn't itself the issue, but I doubt that seriously. It may be worth mentioning whether this behavior also manifests when not interactively debugger. Regardless, definitely Valgrind this.

Comment: I appreciate that.

If the local stack is being overstepped and writing on my parameters, why do the messed up parameters **always** change to 0, and not just whatever random garbage happens to overstep the local stack?

I'll fix the increment mistake and take a look using valgrind tomorrow and see where that gets me.

I guess "_random_" was the wrong word. When a parameter gets changed to 0, it's consistently changed to 0, however I haven't noticed any pattern as to which parameters get changed to 0.

Comment: So, it sounds like this is definitely a stack overflow issue (how appropriate), so I guess the easiest fix would be to make my local stack larger. I'm compiling with arm-none-eabi-g++, so what is the command line argument that I can use to make my stack larger? For that matter, what is the default stack size?